# Can Mathematica warn you about mistyped variables?

Tags: programming, debugging

In other dynamical programming languages like Python, mistyping a variable, e.g. mistyping var1 as bar1 in the example below, immediately results in an error.

```
var1 = 1
var2 = bar1
```

But Mathematica will happily run the code without warning you. In a large program, you don't know something has gone wrong until you see the wrong final result or see a mysterious error that is produced much later in the program.

How do you deal with this problem?

Comment: Mathematica used to have `General::spell` turned on, and you would get messages when the spelling of a new symbol was similar to the spelling of an existing symbol. However, when Mathematica incorporated syntax coloring, this message was turned off, as syntax coloring is a much more useful indicator. In your case, you should have seen that `bar1` was colored blue, not black, indicating that it had no value assigned to it.

Comment: Also `var2=bar1` is a perfectly valid algebraic assignment and Mathematica should not flag an error.